# Can conf_int() be used on predictions from neural network model to calculate confidence interval?

Tags: python, neural-network, time-series, forecasting, confidence-interval

I am new to forecasting and statistics. I have used a neural network model to get forecast for a time series data. However I am unable to get a confidence interval for my forecast. Please help. Can conf_int() work on neural network based predictions? Are there any proxies I can use for confidence interval (like MAPE) etc.

Comment: Hi Hitesh. You should provide more information about your program for anyone to be able to help you. You can add relevant code, what tools did you use, the kind of data you have etc. Otherwise this question is very broad and vague for a reader.

Comment: Are you sure you are asking about confidence intervals? For time series data, typically we look at prediction intervals not confidence intervals.

Comment: Hi Alex, I can work with prediction interval as well. that would be helpful as well.